# "Validate Mesh" in Marlin causes whole test print to be offset from the bed (home)

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, troubleshooting

I have enabled UBL in Marlin firmware for my Ender 3 Pro and generated a mesh which probed the whole bed normally as expected.   However when I use the menu option to Validate Mesh, the whole test print seems to several inches diagonally away from the 0,0,0 home point (see photo).

I don't know what the cause might be or what information I could usefully provide to solve the problem, but here is my configuration.h:  https://pastebin.com/yZkWcMki

[image]

Comment: I guess this wasn't the right place to ask this question?